# How to load data into a RecyclerView inside a fragment using ViewModel

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, model-view-controller, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a app with bottom navigation, that switches between several fragments.

Inside one of these I need to list data in a `recyclerview`. I am rather new to android and I have never used a `recyclerview` or used ViewModels or fragments before so I am not 100% sure if I am doing this the right way.

*Here is what I have right now:*

**Fragment.java**

```java
public class twoFragment extends Fragment implements LifecycleOwner {

    private twoViewModel twoViewModel;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        twoViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(twoViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, container, false);

        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.rv_main);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        twoViewModel.getUserMutableLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), userListUpdateObserver);


        return root;
    }

        private Observer<ArrayList<User>> userListUpdateObserver = new Observer<ArrayList<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<User> userArrayList) {

                recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(requireActivity(),userArrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
            }
        };

}
```

**ViewModel.java**

```
public class twoViewModel  extends ViewModel {

    MutableLiveData<ArrayList<User>> userLiveData;
    ArrayList<User> userArrayList;

    public twoViewModel() {
        userLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

        // call your Rest API in init method
        init();
    }

    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<User>> getUserMutableLiveData() {
        return userLiveData;
    }

    public void init(){
        populateList();
        userLiveData.setValue(userArrayList);
    }

    public void populateList(){

    User user = new User();
        user.setTitle("Darknight");
        user.setDescription("Best video ever!");

        userArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        userArrayList.add(user);
        userArrayList.add(user);
        userArrayList.add(user);
        userArrayList.add(user);
        userArrayList.add(user);
        userArrayList.add(user);

}



}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    Activity context;
    ArrayList<User> userArrayList;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<User> userArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userArrayList = userArrayList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        System.out.println("onCreateViewHolder");
        return new RecyclerViewViewHolder(rootView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        User user = userArrayList.get(position);
        RecyclerViewViewHolder viewHolder= (RecyclerViewViewHolder) holder;

        viewHolder.txtView_title.setText(user.getTitle());
        viewHolder.txtView_description.setText(user.getDescription());
        viewHolder.imgView_icon.setImageDrawable(user.getImgIcon());
        System.out.println("onBindViewHolder");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userArrayList.size();
    }

    class RecyclerViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgView_icon;
        TextView txtView_title;
        TextView txtView_description;

        public RecyclerViewViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgView_icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView_icon);
            txtView_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_title);
            txtView_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_description);
            System.out.println("RecyclerViewViewHolder");

        }
    }
}
```

**The problem**

With this code, the `recyclerview` is **empty** when I open the app. However, when I click on the `EditText` view that I have in the fragment the data appears in `recyclerview`. Then, as soon as I leave the fragment and go back to it, it is empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

*I read somewhere you are not supposed to use ViewModels and recyclerviews together...how does that work?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your twoFragment to:

```
public class twoFragment extends Fragment {

private twoViewModel twoViewModel;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    twoViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(twoViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, container, false);

    recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.rv_main);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    
    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(requireContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

    twoViewModel.getUserMutableLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), userListUpdateObserver);


    return root;
}

    private Observer<ArrayList<User>> userListUpdateObserver = new Observer<ArrayList<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ArrayList<User> userArrayList) {
            recyclerView.setData(userArrayList);
        }
    };
```

}

And change the RecycleView Adapter to:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<User> userArrayList = ArrayList<User>();

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public setData(ArrayList<User> userArrayList){
    userArrayList = userArrayList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
    System.out.println("onCreateViewHolder");
    return new RecyclerViewViewHolder(rootView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    User user = userArrayList.get(position);
    RecyclerViewViewHolder viewHolder= (RecyclerViewViewHolder) holder;

    viewHolder.txtView_title.setText(user.getTitle());
    viewHolder.txtView_description.setText(user.getDescription());
    viewHolder.imgView_icon.setImageDrawable(user.getImgIcon());
    System.out.println("onBindViewHolder");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userArrayList.size();
}

class RecyclerViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgView_icon;
    TextView txtView_title;
    TextView txtView_description;

    public RecyclerViewViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imgView_icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView_icon);
        txtView_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_title);
        txtView_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_description);
        System.out.println("RecyclerViewViewHolder");

    }
}
}
```

Side note: I am pretty sure you do not need to implement LifeCyclerOwner explicitly on a fragment, it already implements it.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see any errors in your code except you need to set the `LayoutManager` to the `RecyclerView`

```
recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.rv_main);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())); // <<< Add this
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Comment: Do I still need to do that if I set  `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"` in my layout file?

Comment: If you did that in layout, so there might be another issue out there; you can do it in either one

Comment: @sundrycode I had sample like yours and it works fine.. So, the provided info should work.. If you'd provide a demo of your app so that we can help

Comment: Sure, how do I do that?

Comment: Probably you can upload it to github or any other code sharing platform

Comment: So, in my effort to put it on Github I found out that your answers fixed the problem that prompted this question, but because I have a second problem with my code it didn't look like it was working.  I would love to ask about this other problem I am having but I don't think it is related enough to ask here. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment may observing different userLiveData instance that's why every time when you leave and go back to fragment ,recycler view is empty.To observe same userLiveData instance use below code.

```
    public class twoViewModel  extends ViewModel {

    MutableLiveData<ArrayList<User>> userLiveData;
    ArrayList<User> userArrayList;

    public twoViewModel() {
        
        // call your Rest API in init method
        init();
    }

    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<User>> getUserMutableLiveData() {
     if(userLiveData==null)
      userLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        return userLiveData;
    }

public void init(){
        populateList();
        getUserMutableLiveData().setValue(userArrayList);
    }
```

Comment: I tried it, but the same thing is still happening.